# Other ways of showing prop-based conditonal text in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

I have a component that renders text based on the users membership status and I want to change the interpolated text based on that prop value. Is there a more efficient way of showing different text based on the prop besides a bunch divs/p tags with`v-if` or `v-show`?

It's just a ton of text to constantly have a bunch of stacked divs.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Cheers!

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { PropType } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  kind: {
    type: String as PropType<'subscribed' | 'unsubscribed'>,
    default: 'subscribed',
  },
  planId: {
    type: String as PropType<'standard' | 'silver' | 'gold' | 'platinum' | 'diamond' | 'no plan'>,
    default: 'standard',
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="c-promotion-plan-card" data-cy="component-promotion-plan-card">
    <div class="flex items-baseline mb-sm">
      <div v-if="planId === 'standard'" class="text-h6 text-dark">Standard Gang</div>
      <div v-if="planId === 'silver'" class="text-h6 text-dark">Silver Foxes</div>
      <div v-if="planId === 'gold'" class="text-h6 text-dark">Golden Girls</div>
      <div v-if="planId === 'platinum'" class="text-h6 text-dark">Platinum Boys</div>
      <div v-if="planId === 'diamond'" class="text-h6 text-dark">Diamond Dudes</div>
      <div v-if="planId === 'no plan'" class="text-h6 text-dark">
        No Plan Posse
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like following snippet (map your plans and use computed property ):

```js
const { ref, computed } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  props: {
    kind: {
      type: String,
      default: 'subscribed',
    },
    planId: {
      type: String,
      default: 'standard',
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const plans = ref([{plan:'standard', name: 'Standard Gang'}, {plan:'silver', name: 'Silver Foxes'}, {plan:'gold', name: 'Golden Girls'}, {plan:'platinum', name: 'Platinum Boys'}, {plan:'diamond', name: 'Diamond Dudes'}, {plan: 'no plan', name: 'No Plan Posse'}])
    const handlePlan = computed(() => plans.value.find(p => p.plan === props.planId))
    return { plans, handlePlan }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.style-class {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.other-style {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="c-promotion-plan-card" data-cy="component-promotion-plan-card">
    <div class="flex items-baseline mb-sm">
      <div class="text-h6 text-dark" :class="handlePlan.plan === 'standard' ? 'style-class' : 'other-style'">{{ handlePlan.name }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! How would you then handle the variable styling with this way? Class binding based on the `planId` or the computed prop?

Comment: @LovelyAndy hey mate, can you give me an example? You mean to style plan depending of planId? btw I rewrited my answer to Composition API

Comment: Yeah, so let's say you have the 'no plan' prop option and you want your card or text to be in purple and maybe larger font and perhaps even another sibling div with subtext that again has it's own style. While the others can be the same across the board with just diffrent filler text. 

Just another layer of complexity I didn't think computed props could really handle

Comment: Ok, you can use computed and just compare `handlePlan.plan` I updated my answer take a look pls

Comment: awesome! Thanks for all the help. I wonder, do you think this is better than having a bunch of conditional statements in your template? Seems almost as verbose/as much setup doing things in your script section. Just curious your preference here:)

Comment: You are welcome.I prefer doing it in script and leaving template as clean as possible :)

Comment: Totally get it! Thanks for all the help on this pretty basic issue

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a better approach.
You can define a computed property like
**Vue2 Syntax**

```
computed: {
 getLabel() {
  // Assuming that 'planId' is the dependency prop
  if(this.planId === 'standard') return 'Standard Gang';
  else if(this.planId === 'silver') return 'Silver Foxes';
  ....
  return 'No Plan Posse' // For 'no plan' condition
 }
```

**Vue3 Syntax**

```
setup(props) {
 // 1.getLabel depends on firstName,lastName.
 const getLabel = computed(() => {
  // Assuming that 'planId' is the dependency prop
  if(props.planId === 'standard') return 'Standard Gang';
  else if(props.planId === 'silver') return 'Silver Foxes';
  ....
  return 'No Plan Posse' // For 'no plan' condition
 });
 return {
  getLabel,
 };
},
```

and then call this computed within interpolation inside you template like

```
<div class="text-h6 text-dark">{{getLabel}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

Computed properties seem like a great idea here and I probably should have started with that, but once variable styling comes into the picture, I sort of dropped the idea of them for whatever reason. 
How would you handle the styling then? Using class binding then like `:class="`${planId ===  'standard' ? 'style-class' : 'other-style' }`" ?

Comment: Again for handling styling you can do something like
`:class="getClass"` where `getClass` will be a computed property